# Get rid of last comma using PHP or Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

**I have tried many different things to do this and all my ideas have failed me.
How do i get rid of the last comma after running this while loop?**

```
<body onload="
    <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($thing3)): ?>
        checkEdits_<?php echo $row['directory_name']; ?>(),
    <?php endwhile; ?>
">
```

It adds the last comma at the end which ruins the whole script.

The php while(loop)  puts this out when ran through the dom:

```
<body onLoad="checkEdits_juk(), checkEdits_HTML(), checkEdits_JAVASCRIPT(), checkEdits_JQUERY(),">
```

except i don't want the last comma at the end. Is their a way to get rid of it?

Comment: Consider refactoring your code to register those onload functions properly instead of shoving them into an inline event handler.

Comment: Although I agree with @ThiefMaster, you can probably replace your comma with an `;` without changing anything else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can put your data in an array and uese the [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function

```
  $directory_names = array();
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($thing3)) {
    $directory_names[] = $row['directory_name'];
  }
  echo implode(', ', $directory_names);
```

Comment: That's actually a good idea. But let's improve the answer with some example code!

Answer (score 3):

```
substr($yourString, 0, strlen($yourString) - 1);
```

This returns a substring of your string that contains everything from the 0th index to the last - 1  position.

Answer (score 1):

With your array of MYSQL rows, use php's join function (implode) http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php

Comment: So i dint use yuor code but what you sent me sparked an idea of not needing commas just ; instead. Thanks for the inspiration!

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use:

```
<body onload="function() {
    <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($thing3)) { ?>
        checkEdits_<?php echo $row['directory_name']; ?>(); 
    <?php } ?>
}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `rtrim` to take off the last comma. I'd rewrite like this:

```
<?php 
$onload = "";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($thing3)) {
    $onload .= "checkEdits_" . $row['directory_name'] . ", ";
}
$onload = rtrim($onload, ', ');
?>

<body onload="<?php echo $onload; ?>">
```

Comment: For some reason that doesnt work. it still has the comma at the last array item. thanks though

Comment: I had a typo. My `rtrim()` didn't account for the space at the end of the string. I've updated the example. It should be good now.